# How can I run Ubuntu on my Droid X2?

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch

How can I install Ubuntu alongside Android Gingerbread on my Droid X2 so that on boot it asks which OS to boot to?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you get involved in porting and work around the obvious hardware limitations and probably missing driver support. The official requirements for Ubuntu on phones were from the Galaxy Nexus (1 GB RAM, 1.2 GHz *dualcore*) but the device was dropped from support and moved to the Nexus 4 (2 GB RAM, 1.5 GHz *quadcore*).

> Verizon promises a 2.3.6 update but Motorola Mobility has confirmed it will never see Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich.
>
> <sup>Wikipedia: [Droid X2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_X#Droid_X2)</sup>

The carriers and manufacturer seem to have dropped support for the device longtime ago. But Ubuntu relies on parts of Android 4.4 in current builds.

> Last update 2013-03-27
>
> [...]
>
> Other Memory issues (512MB)
>
> <sup>Ubuntu Wiki: [Motorola Droid 3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/solana)</sup>

As you can see work on similar ports seems to have been given up a long time ago.

Dual boot seems to be implemented by replacing parts of the recovery ROM and telling Android to boot to the recovery, which will start Ubuntu. At least last time I tried dual booting on my Nexus 4 earlier this year it worked that way.